# Inject Javascript Function not working in Android React Native WebView but work fine in iOS React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

I get a challenge when apply webview. I want to inject Javascript function to my webview, but it only work in iOS not in Android.

**Look to my code :**

Webview :

```
<WebView
                            source={{uri:"http://mywebview.com/webview.php"}}
                            injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                            mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
                            javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                            style={{height: 300}} />
```

**JSCode to Inject :**

```
let jsCode = `function doPopUp() {
                        document.querySelector('#myBody').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                        alert('hello world from webview');
                        }`;
```

> In iOS it works fine, but not in Android. If i not inject the JS (i
>   put it directly in php file) and then open in Android Browser it works
>   fine. Additional information for you is, if i'm not put syntax inside a js function it works fine. Why? and how to fix it?

Comment: set `domStorageEnabled={true}` in `WebView`. hope it works

Comment: unfortunately not working for me.

Comment: where do you call `doPopUp()` function in your `http://mywebview.com/webview.php` file?? Do you have any HTML component with id `myBody`??

Comment: I call it inside button. then function not working only if i inject the script via React Native to Webview. If i put the function inside Webview directly it's working.

Comment: remove single quotes while declaring let jsCode

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution to this problem after a few hours of trying. Something like this will work.

Without the ref, for some reason injectedJavaScript will not run. With the ref set, `webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(runFirstScript);` , injectedJavaScript will run as well.

This was only an issue in IOS, not android.

I've posted this solution to the github issues for react-native-webview as well. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2259

````js
 ...
 
  const webViewRef = useRef();

 const runFirstScript = `
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hi') }, 2000);
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;
    
    const runSecondScript = `
      setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hello') }, 2000);
      true; 
    `;

  if (webViewRef.current != null) {
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(runSecondScript);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <WebView
        ref={ref => (webViewRef.current = ref)}
        cacheEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={runFirstScript} // now injectedJavaScript will trigger along with the ref.
        javaScriptEnabled
        mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
        onMessage={event => {
          //    alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
        }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        scalesPageToFit
        source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
      />
    </>
  );```
````

Answer (score 1):

For android, while adding the javascript function we need to add it as part of DOM. For that, replace `function` with `document` in jsCode.

```
let jsCode = `docuement.doPopUp() {
                        document.querySelector('#myBody').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                        alert('hello world from webview');
                        }`;
```